# Filtering array by parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

I have an array:

```
const submissions = [
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah ?',
    response: 'blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah blah',
    response: 'blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah ?',
    response: 'blah blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: I am new to JS.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];
```

The function takes in the submissions array and a boolean parameter.

```
function filterQuestionsByType(submissions, essayquestion) {

  let trueEssay = [];
  let falseEssay = []; 

  for (let i = 0; i < submissions.length; i++) {
    if ( essayquestion === true) {
      if ( submissions[i].isEssayQuestion === true) {
        trueEssay.push(submissions[i]);
      } else {
        falseEssay.push(submissions[i]);
      }
    } 
  }

  if (essayquestion === true) {
    return trueEssay;
  } else {
    return falseEssay;
  }
}
```

If true I need to return an array with all entries where isEssayQuestion is true. If false, the same. It'll work for true but not false. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just use the `.filter` method for this case

```js
const submissions = [
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah ?',
    response: 'blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah blah',
    response: 'blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah ?',
    response: 'blah blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: I am new to JS.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];

function essays(essay, question) {
   return essay.filter(({isEssayQuestion}) => isEssayQuestion === question)
}

console.log(essays(submissions, false));
console.log("------------------------------------");
console.log(essays(submissions, true));
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) perfectly suits the purpose:

```js
const src = [{question:'blah blah blah ?',response:'blah blah blah',isCorrect:true,isEssayQuestion:false},{question:'blah blah blah blah',response:'blah blah blah',isCorrect:true,isEssayQuestion:false},{question:'blah blah blah ?',response:'blah blah blah blah',isCorrect:true,isEssayQuestion:true},{question:'True or False: I am new to JS.',response:'True',isCorrect:true,isEssayQuestion:false}],

    filterQuestionsByType = (submissions, essayquestions) => 
      submissions.filter(({isEssayQuestion}) => isEssayQuestion == essayquestions)
      
console.log(filterQuestionsByType(src, true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one way to do that. You can simple map your source-array to and write results in new object properties (sortedValues). this method runs only one time, instead of other examples, wich you need to run twice - for true and false.

```
const submissions = [
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah ?',
    response: 'blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah blah',
    response: 'blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'blah blah blah ?',
    response: 'blah blah blah blah',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: I am new to JS.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];

const sortedValues = {
  trueValues: [],
  falseValues: []
}


submissions.map(item => {
  sortedValues[`${item.isEssayQuestion}Values`] = [...sortedValues[`${item.isEssayQuestion}Values`], item]
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedValues, 2,2))
```